# Error with model.compile and model.fit_generator on Keras

Tags: python, keras

Beginner with Keras -- I'm attempting to train a very simple neural network on a series of images from my local folder, but getting an error when I try to use `fit_generator`.

From

```
model.fit_generator(train_batches,steps_per_epoch=33, validation_data=valid_batches,validation_steps=50,epochs=10,verbose=2)`
```

I get the error

```
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

despite the fact that I compile the model in the line immediately about it with

```
model.compile(Adam(0.01),loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
```

which runs without errors. (see pictures).

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Ndm.png), [Image of generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQThg.png),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a rare case where pictures are more useful than code sample.

The image says, the compile cell got number `[206]`, and fit cell is `[210]`.  In between them, you have recreated the model at `[209]`, which deletes the previously compiled model and creates a new one.

I think it will run (unless there is another bug) if you execute the cells from top to bottom again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. There is a bug: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18287

Unfortunately the fix is not yet released.